# Executing standalone Java application (jar) using tomcat

Tags: spring-batch, ibm-mq, executable-jar, tomcat8

I have a requirement to send and receive messages using MQ. I have created a standalone java application (jar) to do this functionality. Now I want to run this jar all time to monitor the queue to receive messages. Is that any way to deploy this jar in tomcat and execute all time? (I have used spring batch and JMS template)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Spring Integration](https://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) framework. You can run this standalone and leverage the `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter />` to listen on your JMS queue. The message-driven endpoint wraps `JMSTemplate` and should suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot deploy the jar by itself on tomcat, and you don't have to run your application on tomcat to keep it running all the time.

You can include your jar into a web application to run it on tomcat